# C++ Interface issues with creating an instance of it

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

So i have an assignment in my C++ class that is asking me to create an abstract base class called Project, and an interface called Task. Now he gave us the driver code for the main, and within it it's asking us to create an instance of the interface "Task", and i keep getting an error saying " you cant create an instance of an abstract base class" Here's my "Task" interface header file and the main.. I hope it's enough.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef TASK_h
#define TASK_h
class Task
{
public:
    Task();
    virtual ~Task();
    virtual void addPrereq(Task *pt) = 0;
    virtual bool ready() = 0;
    virtual bool done() = 0;
    virtual void doIt() =0;
};
#endif
```

And the main:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CompositeProject.h"
#include "MinorProject.h"
#include "SimpleProject.h"
#include "Task.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
// Create tasks

Task* tasks[7];
for (int i = 0; i != 7; ++i)
    tasks[i] = new Task();//This is where my error is coming from
// Set prerequisites
tasks[1]->addPrereq(tasks[0]);
tasks[2]->addPrereq(tasks[1]);
tasks[3]->addPrereq(tasks[2]);
tasks[3]->addPrereq(tasks[4]);
tasks[4]->addPrereq(tasks[0]);
tasks[5]->addPrereq(tasks[4]);
tasks[6]->addPrereq(tasks[3]);
tasks[6]->addPrereq(tasks[5]);

return 0;
}
```

Now to my knowledge the difference between an abstract base class and an Interface is that the abstract base class normally has a protected constructor, and has atleast one pure virtual method. Now an interface has all it's methods pure virtual, to essentially have a template. Now i don't understand how or why my teacher is asking us to create an instance of the interface Task. He explicitly says elsewhere in the assignment, expected files " Task.h and Task.cpp ". I feel like there's a key element I'm missing here. Thanks!

Comment: You're supposed to create a class deriving from `Task`, and create instances of that class instead. Your compiler is right, you cannot create instances of `Task` itself.

Comment: you mean like maybe make the Task interface called iTask and then create a class called Task that uses iTask as interface?

Comment: Yep! `class Task: public iTask` should be approximately what you're looking for.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, the only thing that is throwing me off is the "expected files" line on the assignment... well anyways thanks a lot man! @computerfreaker

Comment: You might want to speak to the professor about that, since by my count you'll want at least four files: the header file containing your interface definition (iTask.h), the header and source for the class implementing the interface (Task.h and Task.cpp), and your main program (main.cpp).

Comment: @computerfreaker i have one last question, the interface class is supposed to implement the method void addPrereq(Task *pt) although in my iTask class it's giving me a syntax error: identifier "Task"

Comment: That's because `iTask` isn't supposed to know about `Task`. You're also not supposed to implement anything in an interface; leave that for `Task`. With those two statements in mind, you should find that `addPrereq(iTask* pt)` works. Then `Task` will just implement that method, and since `Task` inherits from `iTask`, passing an instance of `Task` to `addPrereq` should work.

Comment: @computerfreaker wow i feel so dumb i thought of thought of that haha that makes a lot more sense thank you!

Answer (score 2):

By default you can not create an object of an abstract base class because the ABC acts like a blueprint on which you create your actual implementation. To give you an example you can define a `Shape` abstract base class that has a method called `virtual void form()=0;` for redefining the form of some geometric shape and on that class you can define another class called `Cube` and another one called`Circle`but each one of those classes have inherited the `void form();` function which you need to redefine for both `Cube` and `Circle` classes...so going back to your problem the abstract class should be called Project (as you are saying) and your code should look something like this

```
#ifndef TASK_H
#define TASK_H
class Project { //project is the abstract base class 
    public:
        Project();
        virtual ~Project();
        virtual void addPrereq(Project *pt) = 0;
        virtual bool ready() = 0;
        virtual bool done() = 0;
        virtual void doIt() =0;
};
class Task:public Project { 
        Task();
        virtual ~Task();
        virtual void addPrereq(Task *pt);
        virtual bool ready();
        virtual bool done();
    virtual void doIt();
}
#endif // PROJECT_H
```

In conclusion:

1. when a class declaration contains a pure virtual function, you can't create an object of that class.
2. any method in ABC that is not virtual is inherited like it is defined, if you have a `void move();` function in the `Shape` class then you can use the function in all inherited classes so you don't need to declare all the functions virtual
3. An ABC describes an interface that uses a least one pure virtual function, and clases derived from an ABC use regular virtual functions to implement the interface in terms of the properties of the particular derived class